# What Stellar payment service is this site using?

Tags: payments, checkout

This site accepts XLM payments. How is this implemented here? How would one implement this?

[image: moonitor.io]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website is Moonitor.io.  I have no affiliation with that site.

I asked the web site owner through their contact form and he said:  "a Stellar getaway for WooCommerce"  WooCommerce enables one to sell stuff on a Wordpress Site.  One such gateway is the one by ProPress:  https://prospress.com/sell-with-stellar-using-woocommerce/
That gateway is opensouce on github here:  https://github.com/Prospress/woocommerce-stellar.